# Ruby - show related businesses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Each of my businesses belongs_to a category, so I'm trying to figure out how to show related businesses.

I'd like to limit it to three related businesses.

Thank you!

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_filter :restrict_access, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @businesses = Business.all
    respond_with(@businesses)
  end

  def show
    @business = Business.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != business_path(@business)
        redirect_to @business, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  def new
    @business = Business.new
    3.times { @business.assets.build }
    respond_with(@business)
  end

  def edit
    @business = get_business(business_params)
    @avatar = @business.assets.count
    @avatar = 3-@avatar
    @avatar.times {@business.assets.build}
  end

  def create
    @business = Business.new(business_params)
    if @business.save
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.'
    else
      3.times { @business.assets.build }
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: `post belongs_to a category` thats fine. But what is `Business`? How is it related to `Post` or `Category` and where do you want to show the `related posts`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant related businesses.  I only said posts as I was reading a tutorial that was talking about related posts.

Comment: @KirtiThorat what would the belongs_to code be?

Comment: Let us discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `show` action as below:

```
  def show
    @business = Business.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @others = @business.category.businesses.where.not(id: @business.id).limit(3)
    if request.path != business_path(@business)
        redirect_to @business, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end
```

`@others` will have  <=3 `businesses` other than the current business belonging to the same category of current business. You can then use `@others` in the `show` view easily.